# How to restrict crawling of HTTPS in robots.txt for IIS server?

Tags: iis, robots.txt

is there a way to restrict crawling of HTTPS to one specific folder in robots.txt on IIS? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is that you can add `<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">` to your https site.

You can create second robots.txt file, named as robots_https.txt and add all the entries to block all the content.

Then add the following lines to your .htaccess file (which is located in the root of your web hosted directory).

`RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ robots_https.txt`

Comment: This would limit all traffic, it's not specific to https-traffic.

Comment: you should have to specify https url.

Comment: OP said the server is IIS, which does not use .htaccess files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I think I finally found the answer in this post: http://www.jppinto.com/2010/03/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-on-iis7-using-url-rewrite-2-0/ It's using URL Rewrite provided by IIS to redirect HTTPS request to HTTP, or vice versa. Or if you don't have URL Rewrite plugin installed in IIS server, you can modify Web.Config directly to add rules, as suggested in the post. Cheers.